# prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ splits completely in tower of Galois extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

The following exercise is taken from D.A.Cox's book "Primes of the form $x^2 +ny^2...$"

He uses this in order to prove some intermediate steps before the proof of the main theorem in chapter 5, which solves the problem of determing which primes can be expressed in the form $x^2 + ny^2$, for infinitely many n's (theorem 5.1).

> If $ K \subset M \subset L $ , where $L$ and $M$ are Galois over $K$,
>   then prove that a prime ideal $ \mathfrak p $ of  $ \mathcal O_K$
>   splits completely in $L$ if and only if it splits completely in $M$
>   and some prime of $\mathcal O_M $ containing $\mathfrak p $ splits
>   completely in $L$.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the multiplicativity of the residue class degree and ramification index in towers.  I don't see where Cox covers it (n.m. it's in the exercises), but it's in any other ANT book.  You have $e_{\mathfrak Q | \mathfrak p} = e_{\mathfrak Q|\mathfrak P} e_{\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p}$ and $f_{\mathfrak Q | \mathfrak p} = f_{\mathfrak Q|\mathfrak P} f_{\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p}$ when $\mathfrak Q \supset \mathfrak P \supset \mathfrak p$ is a chain of primes lying in $\mathcal O_L \supset \mathcal O_M \supset \mathcal O_K$ respectively.  To split completely these numbers all need to be $= 1$, and by these formulae $f_{\mathfrak Q | \mathfrak p}$ is $= 1$ iff $f_{\mathfrak Q|\mathfrak P}$ and $f_{\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p}$ are both $= 1$, and the same for $e$.

In a nutshell, residue degree is multiplicative because $[\mathcal O_L /\mathfrak Q: \mathcal O_K / \mathfrak p] = [\mathcal O_L /\mathfrak Q: \mathcal O_M / \mathfrak P][\mathcal O_M /\mathfrak P: \mathcal O_K / \mathfrak p]$ and ramification is multiplicative by exercise 5.15, which you must have done since you're on 5.18 :p

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have any reference in mind that I could look for a proof of these two facts ( the multiplicativity of the res class deg and the ramification index ) ?

Comment: For the residue degree it is literally just the multiplicitivity of field extension degrees like I showed.  For ramification it comes down to factoring p in steps instead of all at once. i.e. p = P^e * (other primes over p) = (Q^e')^e * (other primes over P) * (other primes over p but not P).  As far as a book, Lang or Neukirch are the best ones IMO, but be aware that Cox really is giving a quick and dirty version of things, and to learn it all really thoroughly is going to be a lot more effort (but interesting effort!)

Comment: Oh, and there's Milne if you'd prefer something free.  I never cared much for him but I think I'm in the minority on that: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time!